# FF not setting size on window.open

Tags: javascript

I have a simple JS script including:

```
OpenWindow=window.open("", "newwin", "height=250, width=250,toolbar=no,scrollbars="+scroll+",menubar=no");
```

FF 21.0 opens it to the full size of the browser window.

Chrome and Opera correctly open it to the specified width and height.

Is this a known bug in FF? Is there some way around it?

Comment: Firefox opens a little 250x250 window when I try it. However, browsers give users a lot of control over how new windows are opened. If the browser is configured to always open new windows in browser tabs, there's nothing you can do to override that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the space between height and width in your third argument.

See `strWindowFeatures` @ [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open)

Update:

As Pointy says, this doesn't seem to be the case (and from some testing it certainly doesn't affect me in FF 24). However, quoting from Firefox's tab preferences and settings page:

> If you have chosen to open pages in new tabs, Firefox will ignore this option and will open a new window from a link if the page author specified that the new window should have a specific size, because some pages can only be displayed correctly at a specific size.

So this must have been changed from FF 21 til now. How are you triggering the window.open? I know some browsers differentiate based on event source, meaning you get different results on triggering it in Javascript vs. from a user-initiated event.

Comment: The space won't hurt anything. Browsers are more forgiving than the spec says.  However, you're right that it's good to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Voila! Pointy had the answer.

I hadn't noticed that the window was opening in a new tab.

I unchecked the browser open-in-a-new-tab option, and now I get the properly-sized window.

Thank You!